# Sending vlan-tagged packets from Linux

Tags: linux, vlan

I am novice at networking and am really new to vlan terminology.  I want to separate my network to stuff and guest users depending on the switch port.

I prepared a lab with the following:

1. At **switch** I mirrored the port 10 to port 2.
2. At **machine A** with Linux, I installed `wireshark` and connected to switch at port 2
3. At **machine B** with Linux, I managed to create a vlan interface with id 22 and connected to port 10.

The question is how to send packets tagged with id 22 from machine B to somewhere else, in order to monitor them through machine A?  Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All packets which are sent from the VLAN interface are tagged with the respective VLAN ID. And that interface gets only those packets with its VLAN ID.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can i mark your answer as accepted?

Comment: @StathisAlexopoulos Just click on the grey check mark below the downvote triangle.